# Сравнение части текста в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы, в первой - список соотношений. Город - район. Есть вторая таблица,
в ней - список сетей магазинов. Нужно объединить по сути 2 запроса, причем первый является условием выбора второго и имеет несколько вариантов.

Т.е. нечто вроде

```
Select shop_name from shops_nets where (shops_pos=(район 1))or(shops_pos=(район 2))...
```

и так до количества районов (shop_pos - строка). Как сделать в 1 запрос?

Сам ни фига не пойму, как это правильно описать. ((

**Дополнено.**

Хмм, не имеет по сути значения, но так и быть.

Таблица города

```
    int      id
    VarChar  city
    VarChar  aera
```

Таблица магазины

```
    int      id
    VarChar  screen_name
    VarChar  Position
```

Собственно вот те данные, которые нужны в выборке.

Comment: Структуру двух таблиц можно ?

Comment: хмм, не имеет по сути значения но так и быть

таблица города<br>
`
    int      id
    VarChar  city
    VarChar  aera`

Таблица магазины<br>
`
    int      id
    VarChar  screen_name
    VarChar  Position`

собсно вот те данные которые нужны в выборке.

Comment: а что такое Position ? Как оно относится к таблице городов ?

Предположу что-то следующее:

select screen_name from shops_nets where Position IN (select aera from shop_city WHERE city ="москва")

или 

select screen_name from shops_nets 
inner join shop_city on (shop_city.aera=shops_nets.Position) where  shop_city.city ="москва")

Comment: еще не пробовал ничего из приведенного, но почитав пару усточнений
select Position from shops_net where id =1 даст такой результат: "Район1,Район2,Район3"

т.е. у одной записи весь список точек храниться в этом поле.

select aera from shop_city WHERE city ="москва" вот именно то о чем я говорил

сейчас буду пробовать курить) думаю в правильно направлении чтонить из советов и толкнет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я поняла, Вам требуется выборка магазинов по городу, при том, что связи магазин-город нет, есть только магазин - район. Если в поле Position находится в точности название района, и можно проверять простое равенство строк, то, как уже предлагалось:

```
select screen_name from shops_nets where Position IN (select aera from shop_city WHERE city ="москва")
```

Если в Position (а мне кажется, что именно так и есть) только часть названия района, и нужно определять вхождение названия района в Position - то помогут временные таблицы, т.к. IN уже не прокатит:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp(select aera from shop_city WHERE city ="москва");
select screen_name from shops_nets, tmp where LOCATE(tmp.aera,Position,1)>0;
```

А так вообще, если есть возможность, перепроектируйте БД. Отдельные таблицы городов, районов, и поля ID города и ID района у магазина. И все будет быстрее, проще и более гибко.

Comment: У меня ощущение, что Вы довольно поверхностно понимаете sql. откуда такое упорное нежелание использовать join? впервом приведенном запросе использование IN вместо простого соединения заметно снизит скорость. во втором тоже какая то надуманная конструкция

Comment: В принципе, можно и join'ами.
Нежелание обусловлено тем, что join может серьезно тормозить и в ряде случаев оптимальнее создать временную таблицу. Но Вы правы, это не тот случай

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно поняла вопрос, то примерно так:

```
select shop_nets.shop_name table2.shop_pos from shop_nets table2 where table2.shop_pos = shop_nets.районы
```

Comment: Тут просто синтаксически неправильно написано. Это вы даете таблице псевдоним и на нее условие связи с самой собой. Ему же нужны районы из одного города. Надо было вообще-то показать, как выглядит первая таблица с районами и присоединить ее к запросу. Что-то вроде
 
    select sn.shop_name, sn.shop_pos from shop_nets sn 
        join region r on r.id = sn.shop_pos
        where region.cityID = ?

Comment: Нет, не то, мне не обьединение таблиц нужно, с обьединением проблем не возникает, честно сам с трудом понимаю, как это описать.

Мне надо глянуть все магазины 1 города, но у магазина в положении записан не город, а район. Т.е. сначала мне нужно сделать выборку районов города, а потом уже сравнивать район с положением записаным у магазина.

Т.е. сейчас мне приходитьтся делать первый запрос, и после в цикле прокручивать второй запрос. Хотя по идее можно реализовать в 1 запрос.

Comment: с точностью до имен атрибутов это и есть решение. приведите полностью имена и описание колонок. в запросе shop_name в описании таблицы screen_name и тд. тщательнее